# Update table with ordered values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

i need to update a table ordering by price and reassigning the ordered price.
The price and values are grouped by idcategory. Here is an example:

```
|  ID   | idcategory |  price  | value  |
|   1   |     1      |   10    |   3    |
|   2   |     1      |   12    |  30    |
|   3   |     1      |   43    |   9    |
|   4   |     1      |   32    |  23    |
|   5   |     2      |   38    |  13    |
|   6   |     2      |    8    |  26    |
|   7   |     2      |    3    |  34    |
|   8   |     2      |   10    |  12    |

. .. .. .. .. .. .. ... ... .. .. .. ..
```

I need to reorder the table grouping by idcategory reassigning the ordered value to the ordered price like this:

```
|  ID   | idcategory |  price  | value  |
|   1   |     1      |   10    |   3    |
|   2   |     1      |   12    |   9    |
|   3   |     1      |   32    |  23    |
|   4   |     1      |   43    |  30    |
|   5   |     2      |    3    |  12    |
|   6   |     2      |    8    |  13    |
|   7   |     2      |   10    |  26    |
|   8   |     2      |   38    |  34    |
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ... ..
```

database is a postgres 9.2.

any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks you and Happy new Year !!!

this is the updated working solution based on GarethD suggestion:

```
    WITH OrderedValues AS
    (   SELECT  Value, 
                Price,
                idcategory,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idcategory ORDER BY Value) AS ValueNum,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idcategory ORDER BY Price) AS PriceNum
        FROM    T
    ), OrderedIDs AS
    (   SELECT  ID,
    idcategory,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idcategory ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
        FROM    T
    ), NewValues AS
    (   SELECT  i.ID,
                v.Value,
                p.Price
        FROM    OrderedIDs i
                INNER JOIN OrderedValues v
                    ON i.RowNum = v.ValueNum 
                 AND i.idcategory = v.idcategory

                INNER JOIN OrderedValues p
                    ON i.RowNum = p.PriceNum

                    AND i.idcategory = p.idcategory
    )
    UPDATE  T
    SET     Price = v.Price,
            Value = v.Value
    FROM    NewValues v
    WHERE   v.ID = T.ID;

    SELECT *
    FROM T;
```

Comment: How you are determining the order of this data?

Comment: price and value both by ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to rank your both your IDs (OrderedIDs), and your Price/Value combination (OrderedValues). Then you can matched the corresponding ranks (NewValues), and update your table accordingly:

```
WITH OrderedValues AS
(   SELECT  Value, 
            Price,
            idcategory,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idcategory ORDER BY Value, Price) AS RowNum
    FROM    T
), OrderedIDs AS
(   SELECT  ID,
idcategory,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idcategory ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM    T
), NewValues AS
(   SELECT  i.ID,
            v.Value,
            v.Price
    FROM    OrderedIDs i
            INNER JOIN OrderedValues v
                ON i.RowNum = v.RowNum
                AND i.idcategory = v.idcategory
)
UPDATE  T
SET     Price = v.Price,
        Value = v.Value
FROM    NewValues v
WHERE   v.ID = T.ID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cad81/3)**

Comment: I have to adjust the query cause it is not considering the grouping by idcategory. price and value must be grouped by id_category. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but prices are not ordered, just values. I will try to modify the query. Thank you again

Comment: Just change the columns within the `ORDER BY` part of the `ROW_NUMBER` function in the `OrderedValues` CTE. As long as the partitioning remains the same you can order it however you like.